# A relation with no data has a super key?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, primary-key

Does a **relation** with no data have a **super key** ?

---

I want to answer this question in my University exams but I am confused.

Comment: I know that "[every relation has a PK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_integrity)", and as a result a super key also ([PK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) is a super key). But, what happens with this relation?

Comment: You mean no data in the sense of no rows, or no data in the sense of no columns?

Comment: No rows. Even though I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: In this case you have a normal relation, that has at least a superkey, constituted by all the attributes. The fact that you have an empty instance is purely “accidental”.

Comment: Yes, the whole heading (set of all attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambiguous.

Keys, and therefore superkeys, are a feature of a relation *variable*, AKA relation *schema*. However, the term *relation* is often used quite loosely to mean either a relation schema (a variable), or a relation value (the value of that variable at some point in time), or both. Certainly the keys and superkeys of a relation variable in no way depend on knowing the value of that variable (i.e. the data it contains). By definition every relation variable must have at least one superkey.

In an educational setting students are often expected to deduce superkeys and keys from some given set of dependencies or from sample data values. If you are given no dependencies and no values at all for relation R then you can deduce only that the set of all R's attributes is a superkey (axiomatic for any relation variable).